# for loop calculation not understandable

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
int n,i,inst,tem,x,y,z;
int num[3] = {100,200,300,400};

    for(x=1; x<n; x++){
        for(y=0; y<x; y++){
            if( num[x] = num[y] ){
                printf("\nsame number: %d",num[y]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i have been trying to understand this for 2 days but can't seem to find any answer.

in my calculation there should not be  any "same number" printed in the output screen.but "same number: 100" is showing 6 times.

why 6 times???
why the same number is 100??

any idea???

Comment: `if( num[x] = num[y] )` is wrong. You need `==`.

Comment: @Rsq Zmn The code shall not compile. So at first show a code that compiles.

Comment: There are multiple issues with that "code", like n beining undefined, assignment as condition, array with three elements initialized with four. It makes no sense to ask why some crappy code does not work.

Comment: @Olaf `n` is defined but not initialized, and the compiler will not write more data than there are entries in the array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You are right, of course. No idea whiyh I wrote "undefined" instead of "uninitialized" - sorry. IIRC, the initializer should at least generate a warning which should be paid heed.

Comment: @Olaf No problem, and it seems that I was wrong about the array initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is

```
if( num[x] = num[y] )
```

should be

```
if( num[x] == num[y] )
```

You are using `=` which is assignment and `==` is comparison

Your variable n is not initialized. As n is local, it has some garbage value in it.

And

`int num[3] = {100,200,300,400};` is wrong.

It should be

`int num[4] = {100,200,300,400};`

or

```
int num[] = {100,200,300,400};
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not
>   contained within the entity being initialized.

However in your program you are attempting to provide a value for the element `num[3]` of the array `num` that has only 3 elements.

```
int num[3] = {100,200,300,400};
       ^^^                ^^^^
```

Also variable `n` was not initialized. It has an indeterminate value and as result the program has undefined behaviour because the variable is used in the loops

```
for(x=1; x<n; x++){
    for(y=0; y<x; y++){
        if( num[x] = num[y] ){
            printf("\nsame number: %d",num[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the if statement you are using the assignment operator instead of the comparison

```
if( num[x] = num[y] ){
          ^^^
```

There are many unused variables in the program. And function main should have return type int if you want that the program would be C-compliant.

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int num[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( num ) / sizeof( *num );

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            if ( num[i] == num[j] ) printf( "\nsame number: %d", num[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code as shown will have *undefined behavior*. The values of uninitialized non-static local variables is *indeterminate* and you should not use them before initialization.

You need to initialize `n` to the number of entries in the array (i.e. `3`, or better yet `sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[0])`) or the outer loop will run an indeterminate number of times.

And of course there's the issue with you using *assignment* instead of comparison.

The code should produce multiple warning messages, and if not then you should enable more warnings. Warnings are often indicators that there's something you do that is technically okay, but could lead to problem.